# Prestashop one step checkout programatically change carrier

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6, checkout, carrier

I'm dealing with an issue, I've been working in a module that does pretty much the same as a cart rule if you have certan type of products and a certain amount in your cart, the module sets a free shipping carrier for you, this can be achieved with discount codes I know that, but the requierement was specific, Do that ... without using discount codes, So, the site has enabled the one step checkout, the module does it well in the 5 step checkout, but the hook DisplayBeforePayment does not work, I know that maybe it isn't working because of ajax call, To keep it simple, What can I do to get my module working with the One step checkout? (order-opc Controller). Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to use a different hook. Please have a look at [this](http://www.prestarocket.com/blog/prestashop-1-7-hook-list-liste-des-hooks/) page.
If you search for "DisplayBeforePayment", you see it's only used in /controllers/front/OrderController.php. The 5 step checkout uses this controller.

The one step checkout uses a different controller: /controllers/front/OrderOpcController.php.

The hook DisplayBeforePayment is not present in that controller, so that's why i think your module doesn't work on the one page checkout.

Comment: Aurora, in deed now I'm using actionCartSave to do this, I've another question, i'm enabling and disabling the carrier (free shipping carrier) in order to prevent some user to selec it. I'm selecting it if its enabled ... but wouldn't be better to add a cart rule? instead of enabling and disabling the carrier each time that the amount is > 500 for certain type of products?  i'm setting the carrier in this hook, and also changing the delivery option ... this could bring some trouble? if many customers at same time decide to purchase same products with an amount greater than 500?

Comment: @lfelisiak Hi, please mark the awnser as correct so other people can learn from your question too :). And you are right. Because if your module disables the carrier, a different customer won't be able to select that carrier if a different user has a cart < 500 so i advice against this. You could solve this by checking the total of the cart and if it's < 500, exclude free from the carrier list. I hope i've helped you a bit :)